# Scroll bar is showing above the popup window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

I have Bootstrap responsive table in my page. In responsive view the table showing scroll bar for better view. I have a pop up in that page, in responsive view the scroll bar of the table is showing above the pop up window. How can I hide the scroll bar? Or how can I place the pop up above the scroll bar?

[image: page without pop up]
[image: page with pop up]

Comment: share your code in a fiddle

Comment: check this link
http://sesameindia.net/testing/table/

and switch to responsive view 320, 360, 480, you can see scroll bar in table and launch pop up still you see the scroll bar of table above the pop up.

Comment: Which browser are you using??Am unable to see the issue in the link you provided or am i checking it wrong ?@Dhanil

Comment: Am using the latest version of mozilla.I have resized the browser window to a minimum size and clicked on the button.It showed the modal popup.But still i was unable to find the issue you mentioned@Dhanil

Comment: did you tried with using shift+ctrl+M(in developer options > responsive view}??.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57371/discussion-between-dhanil-and-shadow).

Comment: Should probably upgrade to Bootstrap v3.2.0

Comment: is that a common issue???

Comment: @Dhanil can you provide the solution you found for this so others can now the answer or cause also?